# How can I edit .bsa/.esp file for translation?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I cannot use Nexusmods so I download mods from other sources where no registration is required. I downloaded "UFO-Compatibility-Version-v1.2j-b15-ru", but it shows Russian language in the game, which make me frustrated. So, I want to edit .BSA/.ESP file in order to translate Russian words to English.

Would you please tell me how to edit these files?

Comment: Are you asking us how to translate files, or where to download mods you want?  I'm not sure about the first question, but the second is definitely off-topic.

Comment: I guess it's the former. The latter would help him fix his initial problem, though.

Comment: Why can't you use Nexus Mods? What's stopping you?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Skyrim String Localizer](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/2889/) (you might want to Google it instead of following the link..) to translate ESP files. For BSA files you'll need a [BSA unpacker](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/4804/) and a file editor for the files contained inside the archive.

For most mods translating the ESP file should be enough as BSA usually contains only textures, models, scripts and such.